# DataGridView Change Event on C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, event-handling, eventtrigger

I am currently working on a `DataGridView` and am trying to figure out if there is an Event that gets triggered if anything changed in the Grid. Any Change means not only Value, but also color/add row/delete column/change selection etc. I know there is the `CellValueNeeded` Event, but this event gets triggered multiple times per change. As I observed it actually gets triggered for each cell so if I have a 10x10 DataGridView, it gets triggered 100 times if anything changed. On the other hand, the `CellValueChanged` and `SelectionChanged` Events don't include all cases.

Is there anything that just gets triggered once per change? For me this seems to be an event that should exist.

Comment: How those other things are changed without you directly knowing they are going to change and therefore have a need for events?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but I just need a function to be called anytime something changes to e.g. update the Enabled flag of a button that depends on the row content of ReadOnly Value. I could put it in every event individually, but that does not seem very nice.

Comment: *For me this seems to be an event that should exist* - "any change" is quite a big scope.. Your use case *update the Enabled flag of a button that depends on the row content of ReadOnly Value* doesn't seem so big; why not just use a more targeted event? If you keep your data in something else (datatable) then the event you need might be a function of that thing, not the grid

Comment: The thing is that to Enable or Disable the flag, a function (lets name it funcEnable) has to be called that iterates through a database and checks its values. These values may change when I change the number of row/columns, the selection or the ReadOnly element of one cell. Thus, I would have to call funcEnable in each of the events which is not very clean, especially because it might get called multiple times per change.